# Matlab delete matrix row if first element is in array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I'm trying to delete the row if the first element in that row contains in array.

I've the matrix:

```
A = [ 1 2; 1 5; 2 3; 3 4; 3 5; 4 5 ];
```

And array

```
B = [1,2,3]
```

In ex. I'm cloning A to X

```
X = A
```

And after the selection I should get:

```
X = [4 5]
```

I've tried doing something like this:

```
X(:, 1 == any(B)) = [];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ismember` to check if the value in the first column of `A` (`A(:,1)`) is in `B` and then use the resulting logical array to select the rows of `A` that are not in `B` and assign them to `X`.

```
X = A(~ismember(A(:,1), B),:);
```

**Update**

If you want to check that either the first or second elements is in `B` you can do the following

```
X = A(~any(ismember(A:,1:2), B), 2), :);
```

Or more simply if you're only going to ever have two columns

```
X = A(~any(ismember(A, B), 2), :);
```

Comment: Also, is it possible to check if 1st or 2nd element is a member?

Comment: @sphynx Do you want just the first or second or *any* element in a row?

Comment: well, there are two elements in a row, so I need to know if any (1st or 2nd or both) element(s) is a member of array.